# PowerShell script run from C# is lacking several modules

Tags: c#, powershell

```
var runspace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace()
runspace.Open();
var ps = PowerShell.Create()
ps.Runspace = runspace;
ps.AddCommand(...);
ps.Invoke()
```

Some cmdlets that exist in a regular shell are missing from the runtime started by C#, e.g. all the commands from the [Microsoft.PowerShell.LocalAccounts](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/5.1/microsoft.powershell.localaccounts/microsoft.powershell.localaccounts) module :

```
Error: System.Management.Automation.CommandNotFoundException: The term 'New-LocalUser' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
  at System.Management.Automation.ExceptionHandlingOps.CheckActionPreference(FunctionContext funcContext, Exception exception)
  at System.Management.Automation.Interpreter.ActionCallInstruction`2.Run(InterpretedFrame frame)
  at System.Management.Automation.Interpreter.EnterTryCatchFinallyInstruction.Run(InterpretedFrame frame)
  at System.Management.Automation.Interpreter.EnterTryCatchFinallyInstruction.Run(InterpretedFrame frame)
```

By comparing the `Get-Module -ListAvailable` output from a regular shell and a C# started one I noticed multiple modules are missing :

- AppBackgroundTask
- AssignedAccess
- BitLocker
- ConfigCI
- Defender
- **Microsoft.PowerShell.LocalAccounts**
- MMAgent
- NetworkSwitchManager
- PcsvDevice
- PSWorkflow, PSWorkflowUtility
- SmbShare, SmbWitness
- StartLayout
- WindowsSearch

The version (`$PSVersionTable`) is reported as the same in both shells : 5.1.14393.693

## Edit

Seems to be the same issue & solution : [Why do powershell modules not import when running powershell via start process in c#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23269447/why-do-powershell-modules-not-import-when-running-powershell-via-start-process-i)

Comment: You could use `Import-Module` with the complete path for that module or would have to set/fix the [`PSModulePath`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd878326(v=vs.85).aspx), that would be my guess. For whatever reason it's different in that case.

Answer (score 0):

You can import modules directly on your script instead of trying to do that from C#.

> Import-module bitlocker

For example.

Comment: Does not help. Actually, according to MSDN : `Beginning in Windows PowerShell 3.0, modules are imported automatically when any cmdlet or function in the module is used in a command.`

Comment: Did you check the version of PowerShell that is being started?